# Can you hide layers from the layer panel in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I want to create a template in Photoshop and hide certain layers from the layer panel so they cannot be edited. Is this possible?

Comment: Good question, I am also looking for same functionality, like we have  shy option in AE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the lock icon in the Layers Panel to lock layers you don't want to edit. And if you don't want to see them, you can use the sorting options to sort layers by "Attribute" and "Not Locked" layers.

Comment: Yes but it expands all groups and artboards and won't let us collapse them.